# How to make a grouping, ordering and sorting: Kotlin collection

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, collections, sequence

I'm trying to make a grouping, ordering and sorting per each group a collection according to a Kotlin style as much concise and readable way.

I have a data class.

```
enum class LoadingStatus { PROCESSING, SCANNING, FAIL, FINISHED }

data class FileModel(val loadingStatus: LoadingStatus, val fileName: String, val modifiedDate: Long)
```

I'd like to sort a collection of `FileModel`:

Items are should be sorted in the following order from top to bottom:

`PROCESSING → SCANNING → FINISHED → OTHER`

SubSorting order:

`PROCESSING` → by time modified (AS)

`SCANNING` → by time modified (DE)

`FINISHED` → by time modified (DE)

`OTHER` → by name (AS)

```
private fun setupFilesOrder(incomeList: MutableList<FileModel>): MutableList<FileModel> 
= ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
fun setupFilesOrder(incomeList: MutableList<FileModel>): MutableList<FileModel> {
    val grouped = incomeList.groupBy { it.loadingStatus }
    return listOf(
        grouped[LoadingStatus.PROCESSING]?.sortedBy { it.modifiedDate }.orEmpty(),
        grouped[LoadingStatus.SCANNING]?.sortedByDescending { it.modifiedDate }.orEmpty(),
        grouped[LoadingStatus.FINISHED]?.sortedByDescending { it.modifiedDate }.orEmpty(),
        grouped[LoadingStatus.FAIL]?.sortedBy { it.fileName }.orEmpty()
    ).flatten().toMutableList()
}
```

or even this if you want more expression :)

```
fun setupFilesOrder(incomeList: MutableList<FileModel>): MutableList<FileModel> {
    val grouped = incomeList.groupBy { it.loadingStatus }
    infix fun LoadingStatus.sort(block: List<FileModel>.() -> List<FileModel>) =
        grouped[this]?.block().orEmpty()
    return listOf(
        LoadingStatus.PROCESSING sort { sortedBy { it.modifiedDate } },
        LoadingStatus.SCANNING sort { sortedByDescending { it.modifiedDate } },
        LoadingStatus.FINISHED sort { sortedByDescending { it.modifiedDate } },
        LoadingStatus.FAIL sort { sortedBy { it.fileName } }
    ).flatten().toMutableList()
}
```

Comment: ✔️Dude, this is definitely the beautiful one solution. Looks pretty readable and easy to maintain. 
‼️How would you see this solution which handle the asSequence() to avoid the overhead collection creation?

Comment: Thanks! From my point of view, it doesn't make sense to use `asSequence()` here because you'll traverse the whole list in any case

Comment: That's make sense, marked as an  correct answer. Thanks for the fast reply and you input 